# How to check for multiple values in JEST? (OR-operator)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, automated-tests

how do I check if functions returns one of multiple possible values?

My current test function:

```
const { randomTense } = require('./src/models/functions');

test('Category exists', () => {
    const data = randomTense()
    console.log(data.category)
    expect(data.category).toMatch('past' || 'present' || 'future' );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ['toContain'](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tocontainitem) method like below.

Note that this is not a good test as it's not exhaustive or deterministic. This may fail randomly if your `data.category` is sometimes something else.
Imagine that the function `randomTense` returns four strings in random order: `past`, `present`, `future` and `this is a bug`. In that case this test will pass three times out of four and because it's random it's impossible (it's harder) to predict when it fails.

Testing random functions isn't really a thing. What you usually do in these cases is to separate the function out into smaller bits and mock the random part.

So instead of having a function that does all the things plus the random selection you take all the logic out of it and only leave the random selection which is usually only a line. Then you mock that functionality for your test and test the other function that returns the options/enums.

```js
const { randomTense } = require('./src/models/functions');

const POSSIBLE_VALUES = ['past', 'present', 'future'];

test('Category exists', () => {
    const data = randomTense();
    expect(POSSIBLE_VALUES).toContain(data.category);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! If data.category isn't one of these values then the test needs to fail.

Comment: The problem is that this test fails if your function returns one of the following values randomly: `past` `present` `future` and `something else`. In that case the test passes three out of four times making it non-deterministic.

Comment: I know. I want it to fail if it returns something else. There are no more options to be returned other than past, present and future.